# R finding values in a data frame using | operator vs %in%

Tags: r

I'm trying to find all instances of certain values in a data frame, and replace them with NA. I tried this two different ways that I thought were equivalent, but I get different results. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
df[df == 1 | df == 4] <- NA
```

gives me the expected result:

```
df
#    a  b
# 1 NA  3
# 2  2 NA
```

whereas

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
df[df %in% c(1,4)] <- NA
```

does nothing:

```
df
#    a b
# 1  1 3
# 2  2 4
```

This seems to be because if I use the "|" operator, it searches the data frame element by element, whereas if I use %in% it searches the data frame vector by vector (column by column), but I don't understand why.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
df == 1 | df == 4
#         a     b
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE

df %in% c(1,4)
# [1] FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: `%in%` won't work in the way you wanted in a data.frame.  It work with vectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the code for `%in%`

```
function (x, table) 
 match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
```

So, it is basically doing a `match`.  The output of `match` would be

```
match(c(1,4), df, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
#[1] FALSE FALSE
```

---

`%in%` is applied on `vector`s instead of `data.frame`.  So, we loop through the columns using `lapply`, then do the `%in%`

```
lapply(df, `%in%`, c(1, 4))
```

If we need how the `matrix`, then use `sapply`

```
df[sapply(df, `%in%`, c(1, 4))] <- NA
```

We can check the `match` works on a `vector`

```
sapply(df, match, x = c(1,4), nomatch = 0L) > 0
#         a     b
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

`%in%` is only for vectors. In order to perform it on a dataframe you would have to use `sapply` to apply a function across each of the columns.

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) x %in% c(1, 4))] <- NA

   a  b
1 NA  3
2  2 NA
```