# R: Multiply values values based on a logical conditionin in a data frame with NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators

If you have a full data frame, it easy to multiply values based on a logical condition:

```
df = data.frame(
    var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1),
    var3 = c(5, 4, 3, 4, 5)
)

> df
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1    5
2    2    2    4
3    3    3    3
4    4    2    4
5    5    1    5

> df[df > 2] <- df[df > 2] * 10

> df
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1   50
2    2    2   40
3   30   30   30
4   40    2   40
5   50    1   50
```

However, if you have NA values in the data frame, the operation fails:

```
> df_na = data.frame(
    var1 = c(NA, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, NA),
    var3 = c(5, NA, 3, 4, 5)
)

> df_na
  var1 var2 var3
1   NA    1    5
2    2    2   NA
3    3    3    3
4    4    1    4
5    5   NA    5

> df_na[df_na > 2] <- df_na[df_na > 2] * 10
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df_na > 2, value = c(NA, 30, 40, 50,  : 
  'value' is the wrong length
```

I tried, for example, some `na.omit()` tactics but could not make it work. I also could not find an appropriate question here in Stack Overflow.

So, how should I do it?

Comment: `df_na[!is.na(df_na > 2)] <- df_na[!is.na(df_na > 2)] * 10`

Comment: Thank you all for quick and good answers! I prefer maydin's and lks_swrx's versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `!is.na()` as an additional logical argument to subset by:

```
df_na[df_na > 2 & !is.na(df_na)] <- df_na[df_na > 2 & !is.na(df_na)] * 10

# > df_na
#   var1 var2 var3
# 1   NA    1   50
# 2    2    2   NA
# 3   30   30   30
# 4   40    1   40
# 5   50   NA   50
```

Alternatively, a `dplyr` / `tidyverse` solution would be:

```
library(dplyr)

df_na %>% 
  mutate_all(.funs = ~ ifelse(!is.na(.x) & .x > 2, .x * 10, .x))
```

**Added based on OP comment:**

If you want to subset by values based on the `%in%` operator, opt for the `dplyr` solution (the `%in%` operator won't work the same way here as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47538046/13534060) post):

```
df_na %>% 
  mutate_all(.funs = ~ ifelse(!is.na(.x) & .x %in% c(3, 4), .x * 10, .x))

#   var1 var2 var3
# 1   NA    1    5
# 2    2    2   NA
# 3   30   30   30
# 4   40    1   40
# 5    5   NA    5
```

This approach generally lends itself to more complex manipulation tasks. You may, for instance, also define additional conditions with the help of `dplyr::case_when()` instead of the one-alternative `ifelse`.

Comment: How about using a list for filtering the values? `df_na[df_na %in% c(3, 4) & !is.na(df_na)] <- df_na[df_na %in% c(3, 4) & !is.na(df_na)] * 10` filters columns insted of values.

Comment: The `%in%` operator only works on vectors (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47538046/13534060) answer). If you want to subset the values based on the `%in%` operator, opt for the `dplyr` solution instead - this will work: `mutate_all(df_na, .funs = ~ ifelse(!is.na(.x) & .x %in% c(3, 4), .x * 10, .x))`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work, Using base R:

```
df_na[] <- lapply(df_na, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x) & x > 2, x * 10, x))
df_na
  var1 var2 var3
1   NA    1   50
2    2    2   NA
3   30   30   30
4   40    1   40
5   50   NA   50
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the multiplication, it is with the array indexing.
(`df_na > 2` returns NAs).

You can convert the line below into one line if you like,

```
inds <- which(df_na > 2, arr.ind = TRUE)
df_na[inds] <- df_na[inds] * 10
```